# Custom pseudocode style

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pseudocode

I want to write a custom pseudocode in latex in a similar style as the exemple below: [image].

I didn't manage to get what I want using existing pseudocode package, is there another way to get this kind of setting with well defined alignements?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far ... It is much more easier for us to help you if we can see what you have tried ... BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Following are two examples of how to typeset the pseudocode.

The first example uses the cryptocode package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cryptocode) which gives you a lot of flexibility when writing pseudocode. The syntaxhighlighting is a bit slow to render so you might go for draft mode or do manual highlighting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cryptocode}
\begin{document}

\procedure[mode=text,keywords={Given,DO,While,END While,END DO},syntaxhighlight=auto]{Algorithm name.}{
Given: \\
$(A,B,C,D)$ -- Some parameters. \\
$n$ -- Another parameter. \\
$k$ -- Yet another pamareter. \\
$N$ -- Yet another pamareter. \\
\\
DO: \\
\textbf{1.} First step description:\\
\t for $j=1:n$\\
\t Loop definition\\
While(condition $<N$) \\
\t \textbf{2.} Second step description. \\
\vdots \\
\\
END While \\
END DO \\
\textbf{6.} Return (some variable)
}


\end{document}
```

This yields the following result:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the listings package which offers a large number of options to customize how algorithms are presented. Here is a fairly simple configuration

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
    emph={Given,DO,While,END},
    emphstyle={\bfseries}
}

\begin{lstlisting}[title={\bf\underline{Algorithm name.}}]
Given: 
(A,B,C,D) -- Some parameters. 
n -- Another parameter. 
k -- Yet another pamareter. 
N -- Yet another pamareter. 

DO: 
1. First step description:
    for j=1:n
    Loop definition
While(condition <N) 
    2. Second step description. 
...

END While 
END DO 
6. Return (some variable)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]